# Create left and inner join query with extension method linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
    select *
From Item i inner join Order o on i.OrderId = o.Id
        left join OrderDealersByDistance d on o.Id = d.OrderId
        left join SubOrder s on i.SubOrderId = s.Id
where d.[Status] = 1
```

I would like to write above query with entity framework. I prefer to DataContext and extension methods. How can I write above query?

Comment: You should be more specific. you cannot define the whole problem and expect a whole ready answer. you need to try something first, if it failed, then ask a question about how to fix it. No one knows your level of knowledge of linq, so no one can help you.

Comment: You have not displayed much effort to resolve this on your own. Rework your question to show some effort, and you will get more and better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'd use the query syntax as it's much more readable.

It would look something like this

```
var db = new MyDbContext(conStr);

var query = from i in db.Items
     from o in db.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == i.OrderId)
     from d in db.OrderDealersByDistance.Where(d => d.OrderId == o.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
     from s in db.SubOrders.Where(s => i.SubOrderId == s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
     where d.Status == 1
     select new { Item = i, Order = o, c.ContractName, Distance = d, SubOrder = s };

var result = query.ToList();
```

The `DefaultIfEmpty()` method gives you a left join.
You might want to be more specific about the select list (named columns instead of '*').